# How to send an http request using snap-framework?

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I want to send an http request to an external API using the Snap framework. Does Snap support it? If not, how to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at using [`Network.Wreq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.4.1.0/docs/Network-Wreq.html)?

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LAZ
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as CHA

makeRequest :: IO (Network.Wreq.Response LAZ.ByteString)
makeRequest = do
   res <- get "https://www.example.com"
   let resBody = res ^. responseBody :: CHA.ByteString
   return (resBody)
```

Uses simple lens syntax and supports HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: I was hoping snap support it, but apparently I must use a library. I will check it out.

Comment: Snap is an HTTP server, not a client.  There are a number of HTTP client libraries you could use.  The one that is probably the "closest" to snap is [http-streams](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-streams).  Both snap and http-streams are built on top of [io-streams](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/io-streams).